# Laravel 6 Multiple Authentications (Login Forms)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a problem that I'm facing with Laravel 6 LTS version. I have 3 different controllers: `AdminController (/admin)`, `ScheduleController (/schedule)` and `ClientController (/client)`. Each of those controller should authenticate different database table of users. For `/admin` it uses 'users' table, for `/schedule` it uses 'companies' table and for `/client` it uses 'clients' table. Technically, you should be able to login to each "controller" without the worry of colliding with other controllers. For instance, you can be logged in to `/admin` and also to `/client` and `/schedule` (separate login form for each). How should I go about this? Can someone point me in the right direction? Is this possible with Laravel?

Thanks

Comment: You should look into laravel multi auth. Check: https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986

Answer (score 1):

You can set different user providers in config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)